# How to insert comma as superscript in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, superscript

I want to add comma in spread sheet as a superscript like :
in this ->> ¹,²
comma is not as superscript. Is there any way out for comma to be added as superscript in google spreadsheet?
For 1 and 2 and many others, there is a function available in sheet like =char(178)
however I am ot able to find the code for comma.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*As there is no Unicode for a superscript comma, you can not do this.*

#### More Information:

Not all characters have superscript-versions set in unicode. You can see the full list of available superscript characters [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).

You can either use the dot operator (U+2265) `⋅`, or the modifier letter apostrophe (U+02BC) `ʼ` as separators instead, if you wish to hard code this. I am of the personal opintion that the dot operator looks more like a comma, but they both appear as below:

> ¹⋅² (dot operator)
>
> ¹ʼ² (modifier letter apostrophe)

As Google Sheets isn't a word processing application, there is no direct in-built way to make text appear as superscript, akin to `<sup>1,2</sup>` in HTML:

> <sup>1,2</sup>

#### References:

- [Unicode subscripts and superscripts - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)